# I logon via ssh and the first command is always screen. Can I make it either reconnect to same sesson or make a new one if one does not exist?

Tags: command-line, ssh, unix, gnu-screen

Basically what I want to do is something like this:

screen -session-name=mydefaultscreen

and if the 'session name' of mydefaultscreen doesn't exist, it creates it. if it does exist already then it reattaches to it.

I know i can do screen -x $somenumberhere but i want it all automatic

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running GNU tools on a windows system or are we talking about linux systems?  I'll assume the later, but let me know if I asume incorrectly.

Look at the man pages for the "reconnect" options screen offers.  If my memory serves, "-r" and "-R" are the ones you will be looking for and there is a difference between them.  I'll need some more details about what you are experiencing to completely describe the way to "automatically" do what you asked, but in short it might require a small script to accomplish.  That would be for the more complicated case.  If you have a simpler usage scenario and requirements, then you could simply put a line or two into the appropriate shell hook (e.g. if you use the bash shell, then .bash_profile, .bashrc, ... will execute/evaluate their contents depending on the scenario).

Are you getting dropped or timed-out of your session often?  If so, there may be some SSH options that need to be tweaked too.  What you are asking is do-able, I just need a better understanding of the parameters that the solution must be designed under.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.bashrc` file, you could check if `$SSH_CONNECTION` (which describes whether the current user is logged in via SSH) is set and `TERM` not `"screen"` (which is the case if you run it from within screen), alternatively check the value of `$SHLVL` (which describes the level of nested shells).

Something like the following in your .bashrc should do to automatically start screen if you log in via SSH:

```
if [ -n "${SSH_CONNECTION}" -a ${SHLVL} -eq 1 ]; then
    screen -RD
fi
```

It should re-attach you to the last screen session or create a new one if necessary. Note that other users of that session will be detached. You might also want to have a look at the various other permutations described in the manpage.

```
   -d -r   Reattach a session and if necessary detach it first.
   -d -R   Reattach a session and if necessary detach or even create it first.
   -d -RR  Reattach a session and if necessary detach or create it. Use the first session if more than one session is available.
   -D -r   Reattach a session. If necessary detach and logout remotely first.
   -D -R   Attach  here and now. In detail this means: If a session is running, then reattach. If necessary detach and logout remotely first.  If it was not running create it and notify the user. This is the author's favorite.
   -D -RR  Attach here and now. Whatever that means, just do it.
```

Of course, you could also just set screen as your login shell.